# What string format is this? How do I decode

Tags: php, json, wordpress, string

I have found this on the WordPress theme database in the meta_value section

a:2:{i:0;i:141;i:1;i:462;}

Comment: This is serialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a serialised array.
You can use the following to decode it and access it through PHP.

```
<?php
//Decode the string
$decode = unserialize('a:2:{i:0;i:141;i:1;i:462;}');    

//Decode will give you this
Array (
 [0] => 141
 [1] => 462
)

//Accessible by
echo $decode[0]; //will give you 141
echo $decode[0]; //will give you 462

?>
```